# How to iterate with lambda passing a list with two argument and have then separeted

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am working with lambda, and got stuck with the following problem:

I have a dataframe that has a list with two values (e.g., (x,y)) in just one column of the dataframe.
Usually, I would do the following to get the values separeted:

```
for x,y in df.new:
    df['final'] = x*y
```

But how can I do that with lambda?

I tried:

```
df['final'] = df['new'].apply(lambda x,y:x*y)
```

but it doesn't work.

Has anyone an idea of how it works with lambda?

[image: My df]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```py
df['final'] = df['new'].apply(lambda x: x[0]*x[1])
```

Comment: Great to hear :)
Maybe upvote the answer then and mark it as the right answer, so people having a similar problem will know immediately that the solution works :)

Comment: the voting up [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) is obtained at 15 reputation points, which is clearly not the case with the OP here